# IPv4Address empty when doing a Get-ADComputer

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a list of computers and their IP addresses.  I am trying the following code `get-adcomputer -identity *computername* | select name,IPv4Address` but the IP address column is all blank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `IPv4Address` is not a default property that the `get-adcomputer` displays you need to tell the cmdlet to include the property by using the `-Properties` flag

```
get-adcomputer -identity computer -properties IPv4Address | select name,IPv4Address
```